# Field reductions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If there is a field $F$ that is a field reduction of the real numbers, that is $F(a)=\mathbb{R}$ for some $a$, let's also denote this $F=\mathbb{R}(\setminus a)$, then given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is there a general method to determine whether $x$ is in $F$ or $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}\setminus F$ ?

Comment: The answer probably depends on how F is given... Can you describe F explicitly? I do not know a single example!

Comment: All you know is that F(a)=R, and anything you can deduce from that.

Answer (score 11):

In fact there are no nontrivial "field reductions" of $\mathbb{R}$: if $\mathbb{R} = F(a)$, then $a \in F$ and $F = \mathbb{R}$.

Case 1: $a$ is algebraic over $F$, hence $F(a) = F[a]$, so $d = [F[a]:F]$ is finite.  Then $[\mathbb{C}:F] = 2d$, i.e., "the" algebraic closure of $F$ has finite degree over $F$.

---

Theorem: Let $K$ be a field and $\overline{K}$ any algebraic closure.  If $[\overline{K}:K] = d$ is finite, then $d = 1$ or $d = 2$.

Proof: This is essentially the Grand Artin-Schreier Theorem (see e.g. Section 12.5 of [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/FieldTheory.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/FieldTheory.pdf) for a proof of that.)  Namely, Artin-Schreier says that if $\overline{K}/K$ is a finite **Galois** extension, then the degree is either $1$ or $2$.  Certainly $\overline{K}/K$ is normal.  And for the purposes of this question we are in characteristic zero, so everything is separable.  Therefore $\overline{K}/K$ is Galois.  (But here is a proof of the separability in the general case: if $\overline{K}/K$ is not separable, then there is a nontrivial subextension $L$ such that $[\overline{K}:L] = p^n$ and $\overline{K} = L(a^{p^{-n}})$.  But this is impossible: the polynomial $t^p - a$ is irreducible over $L$ iff all of the polynomials $t^{p^n} - a$ are irreducible over $L$.  So $\overline{K}/K$ is separable.)

---

Thus we must have $d = 1$, i.e., $F = \mathbb{R}$.

Case 2: $a$ is transcendental over $F$.  But then the field $F(a)$ is isomorphic to the rational function field $F(t)$.  Such a field cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, because it admits finite extensions of degree $n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, e.g.
$F(t^{\frac{1}{n}})$.

Comment: Thanks Pete. What then is the largest subfield of R that doesn't contain the square root of 2 for example ?

Comment: @Mouswi: such fields exist by Zorn's Lemma, but they are far from unique: for instance, I can choose one such field which contains $\sqrt{-1}$ and another such field which contains $\sqrt{-2}$, but there is no field which contains both of these elements.

Comment: @Pete They are not subfields of $\mathbb{R}$, but one gets the idea :-) To address Mouswi's implicit question: such an extension will certainly not be simple. Actually, it is not immediately clear to me whether this extension can be chosen to be algebraic.

Comment: @Alex: Good point! Take for instance $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ instead.  And by the way, please feel free to suggest a rephrasing / followup question.  Do you mean the following: if $K$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ maximal with respect to the exclusion of $\sqrt{2}$, is $\mathbb{R}/K$ algebraic?  I think it certainly can be: first adjoin to $\mathbb{Q}$ the elements of a transcendence basis...

Comment: @Pete That's exactly what I meant and I think you have just answered it, thanks! In fact, it shows that $K$ must be of this form: adjoining a transcendent element will never destroy the exclusion property.

Comment: In what sense are two different fields maximal with respect to the exclusion of sqroot 2 ? What cardinality are these sets ?

Comment: @Mouswi: they are maximal elements in the partially ordered set of subfields of $\mathbb{R}$ which do not contain $\sqrt{2}$.  In other words, such a field $K$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which does not contain $\sqrt{2}$ but any strictly larger subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ must contain $\sqrt{2}$.  Anyway, perhaps it is time for you to tell us a little about the context of your question.  Where did you get the idea of "field reduction"?

Comment: Also what is the cardinality of the set of all the maximal sets here?

Comment: (And any such field $K$ as above has the same transcendence degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{R}$ itself, hence has cardinality equal to that of $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @Mouswi: that sounds like a new question.

Comment: Where did I get the idea ? I'm afraid I can't really remember. It's been knocking about in my head for some time. What would happen if you removed an element - then you would have to remove a whole load of other elements but what would you be left with ?

Comment: More on the idea: reducing Q($\sqrt2$) to Q by removing $\sqrt2$ and all its arithmetic combinations seemed not too difficult, but how do you remove $\sqrt2$ from R ? That seemed dificult.

Comment: Having read the above answers about more than one maximal subfield then perhaps removing $\sqrt2$ from Q($\sqrt2$) is not as easy as I thought. Do you get the same issue here ?

Comment: Then I noted the phrase arithmetic combinations is like arithmetic conbinatorics. Does that subject have anything to say about this ?

Comment: I suppose the next thing is to talk about algebraic reductions and transcendental reductions.

Comment: By some time I mean it occurred to me a few weeks ago, and then believe it or not I was reminded about it when I looked at the top rep users on Mathoverflow, found your name Pete, looked at your web page and found the paper on Transcendental Galois Theory. So I was quite tickled when you answered my question here.

Comment: I was looking at top rep users on MO to see if there was any new discoveries by them that could be added to Wikipedia. I didn't get very far with that. Joel's papers were too difficult to read.

Comment: I was going to ask this question on MO, but it seems safer to ask questions here rather than risk them being closed on MO for not being research level.