# Is there a subfield F of the complex field with [C:F]=3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the condition for a field to make the degree of its algebraic closure over it infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23729/what-is-the-condition-for-a-field-to-make-the-degree-of-its-algebraic-closure-ove)

More generally, what is known about subfields $\mathbb{F}\subset \mathbb{C}$ such that the degree $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{F}]$ is finite?  We all know, for example, that $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{C}]=1$ and $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}]=2$ (or we *should* all know this).  However, $\mathbb{C}$ has *many* subfields.  Can you construct/identify one with $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{F}]=3$?

This is a question which I think about whenever I teach abstract algebra.

Comment: Those are the only possibilities. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23729/what-is-the-condition-for-a-field-to-make-the-degree-of-its-algebraic-closure-ove .